# Github v4 GraphQL API - access Marketplace App results (Travis CI)

Tags: graphql, automated-tests, travis-ci, github-api

We are using Travis CI to run tests for one of our repositories on Github.
When looking at the list of commits, we see green check-marks or red crosses, indicating the status of our tests.

[image]

Now I'm experimenting with the Github v4 GraphQL API.
I can browse the API (using GraphiQL and GraphiQL-explorer), but I cannot find the results of the Travis tests anywhere.

Can I use the Github GraphQL API to get the Travis results and how?

Answer (score 0):

When requesting the last commit or a list of commit (with `history`) you can access [`status` object](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/status/#status) which has a [`state` property](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/status/#fields) :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "bertrandmartel", name: "metec-braille-driver") {
    refs(first: 100, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
      nodes {
        target {
          ... on Commit {
            status {
              state
              contexts {
                description
                createdAt
                state
              }
            }
            history(first: 100) {
              nodes {
                message
                status {
                  state
                  contexts {
                    description
                    createdAt
                    state
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which has the following result :

```graphql
....
"status": {
  "state": "FAILURE",
  "contexts": [
    {
      "description": "AppVeyor build failed",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-09T02:31:19Z",
      "state": "FAILURE"
    },
    {
      "description": "The Travis CI build passed",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-09T02:31:42Z",
      "state": "SUCCESS"
    }
  ]
},
....
```

Also from the [v3 doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#statuses):

> The state of the status. Can be one of error, failure, pending, or
>   success

Comment: I try to use the same query, but in our case the result is ```status: null```, even though there are green checkmarks on the github webpage, as shown in the image (that I just added). Any idea why that is?

Comment: @HendrikJan Maybe you are using a token which doesn't have `repo:status` scope ?